# Weird issue with saving to SQL database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, command

I have managed to create a connection to the database and am able to save information to it from my form, the form contains 22 textboxes, a save and another exit button.

I have set the form to retrieve data in the form_load. I have used the "UPDATE" SQL command on the save button and it does save the data on all 22 textboxes (all textboxes are linked to their separate columns). But only one record will be needed that is why I did not use the "INSERT" command.

The problem arises when I click the save button, all (19) textboxes are saved but when I retrieve the text (by reloading the form), each of the 20, 21, 22 textboxes (only) the text  of the 20th textbox keeps on moving tho the next textbox e.g. 20>21>22>20>21>22 is interchanged amongst themselves.

Please help me (I googled this but found nothing on this) and please tell me why this is happening.

The code is below:

```
Dim sqCon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MegaDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI")
    Dim sqCmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand

    sqCmd.Connection = sqCon

    Dim DatabaseErrorMsg As String = "Unable to save the details. Please contact the program developers."
    Dim DatabaseErrorTitle As String = "Database Editing Error"
    Dim DatabaseDoneSave As String = "New records made/updated successfully"

    Dim CompNmtxtS As String
    Dim TrdNmtxtS As String
    Dim ComRegtxtS As String
    Dim WTNmtxtS As String
    Dim VRegtxtS As String
    Dim TextBox1S As String
    Dim ComPosttxtS As String
    Dim StrAddrtxtS As String
    Dim ComCitytxtS As String
    Dim ComCounttxtS As String
    Dim RegAddrtxtS As String
    Dim ComZiptxtS As String
    Dim RepTeltxtS As String
    Dim ComFaxtxtS As String
    Dim RepCelltxtS As String
    Dim W_URLtxtS As String
    Dim EWebtxtS As String
    Dim BankNametxtS As String
    Dim BankBranchtxtS As String
    Dim BraCodetxtS As String
    Dim BankAcctxtS As String
    Dim TextBox2S As String
    CompNmtxtS = CompNmtxt.Text
    TrdNmtxtS = TrdNmtxt.Text
    ComRegtxtS = ComRegtxt.Text
    WTNmtxtS = WTNmtxt.Text
    VRegtxtS = VRegtxt.Text
    TextBox1S = TextBox1.Text
    ComPosttxtS = ComPosttxt.Text
    StrAddrtxtS = StrAddrtxt.Text
    ComCitytxtS = ComCitytxt.Text
    ComCounttxtS = ComCounttxt.Text
    RegAddrtxtS = RegAddrtxt.Text
    ComZiptxtS = ComZiptxt.Text
    RepTeltxtS = RepTeltxt.Text
    ComFaxtxtS = ComFaxtxt.Text
    RepCelltxtS = RepCelltxt.Text
    ComFaxtxtS = ComFaxtxt.Text
    W_URLtxtS = W_URLtxt.Text
    EWebtxtS = EWebtxt.Text
    BankNametxtS = BankNametxt.Text
    BankBranchtxtS = BankBranchtxt.Text
    BraCodetxtS = BraCodetxt.Text
    BankAcctxtS = BankAcctxt.Text
    TextBox2S = TextBox2.Text
    Try

        '*NOTE: UPDATE function will only UPDATE the fields when there is already something in there, as it cannot work for the INSERT command
    'Format for UPDATE command: USE DatabaseName; UPDATE Tablename SET ColumnName = '" & declared string name & "'"
        sqCmd.CommandText = ("USE MegaDatabase; UPDATE CompDetails SET CompName = '" & CompNmtxtS & "', TradeName = '" & TrdNmtxtS & "', CompReg = '" & ComRegtxtS & "', WTnum = '" & WTNmtxtS & "', VATregNo = '" & VRegtxtS & "', TaxPeriod = '" & TextBox1S & "', CompPostalAddr = '" & ComPosttxtS & "', CompPhysAddr = '" & StrAddrtxtS & "', CompCity = '" & ComCitytxtS & "', CompCountry = '" & ComCounttxtS & "', CompProvince = '" & RegAddrtxtS & "', CompZip = '" & ComZiptxtS & "', CompTel = '" & RepTeltxtS & "', CompFax = '" & ComFaxtxtS & "', CompCell = '" & RepCelltxtS & "', CompWebsite = '" & W_URLtxtS & "', CompEmail = '" & EWebtxtS & "', CompBankName = '" & BankNametxtS & "', CompBranchName = '" & BankBranchtxtS & "', CurrentTaxTable = '" & TextBox2S & "', CompBranchCode = '" & BraCodetxtS & "', CompAccNo = '" & BankAcctxtS & "'")

    sqCon.Open()
    sqCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(DatabaseErrorMsg, DatabaseErrorTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    Finally
        Me.Close()
        frmMDImainform.MainMenuStrip.Enabled = True
        MessageBox.Show(DatabaseDoneSave, "Done Saving...", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End Try
```

For the loading part:

```
     Try
        sqCmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 [CompName],[TradeName],[CompReg],[WTnum],[VATregNo],[TaxPeriod],[CompPostalAddr],[CompPhysAddr],[CompCity],[CompCountry],[CompProvince],[CompZip],[CompTel],[CompFax],[CompCell],[CompWebsite],[CompEmail],[CompBankName],[CompBranchName],[CurrentTaxTable],[CompBranchCode],[CompAccNo] FROM [MegaDatabase].[dbo].[CompDetails]"
        sqCon.Open()
        sqRdr = sqCmd.ExecuteReader()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try



Do While sqRdr.Read() 'No need for VbTab and Vb crlf
            CompNmtxt.Text = CompNmtxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(0)
            TrdNmtxt.Text = TrdNmtxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(1)
            ComRegtxt.Text = ComRegtxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(2)
            WTNmtxt.Text = WTNmtxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(3)
            VRegtxt.Text = VRegtxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(4)
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(5)
            ComPosttxt.Text = ComPosttxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(6)
            StrAddrtxt.Text = StrAddrtxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(7)
            ComCitytxt.Text = ComCitytxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(8)
            ComCounttxt.Text = ComCounttxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(9)
            RegAddrtxt.Text = RegAddrtxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(10)
            ComZiptxt.Text = ComZiptxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(11)
            RepTeltxt.Text = RepTeltxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(12)
            ComFaxtxt.Text = ComFaxtxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(13)
            RepCelltxt.Text = RepCelltxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(14)
            W_URLtxt.Text = W_URLtxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(15)
            EWebtxt.Text = EWebtxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(16)
            BankNametxt.Text = BankNametxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(17)
            BankBranchtxt.Text = BankBranchtxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(18)
            BraCodetxt.Text = BraCodetxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(19)
            BankAcctxt.Text = BankAcctxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(20)
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(21)
        Loop
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: Please check the edit sorry had to include the declarations

Comment: @WouterdeKort please check the edited one

Comment: Did you already check which value is saved to which database column? Can you confirm that the actual error isn't in **reading** the values when reloading the form?

Comment: @Filburt I added that one in too please see it, because I checked it and did not find any problems.

Comment: @Armaan Please also add the query you use for reading - since you asign the TextBox values by accessing the resultset fields by index I suspect your problem is the order of columns returned by your reading query.

Comment: @Filburt I Have added that one in now please have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mixup in the order of your columns in your query vs. accessing the columns by index when reading your resultset:

In your query column #21 (last column, zero-based index) is `[CompAccNo]` but when reading you assign column #21 to TextBox2.Text.

I'd suggest you rather access your columns by name when reading:

```
CompNmtxt.Text = CompNmtxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue("CompName")
TrdNmtxt.Text = TrdNmtxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue("TradeName")
ComRegtxt.Text = ComRegtxt.Text & sqRdr.GetValue("CompReg")
'...
```

Another point: Get rid of creating your update query by concatenating user input - use [Command Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) instead!

Comment: Thanks a few people also told of that concatenating but I didnt seem to care....so maybe now I'll try, thanks